# Получение списка со словарем в python

Tags: python

есть два списка со словарями :

```
dict_groups = [{'name': 'Новые Альбомы', 'gid': 4100014},
{'name': 'Synthpop [Futurepop, Retrowave, Electropop]', 'gid': 8564},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\leftfield', 'gid': 101522128},
{'name': 'Бренд одежды | MEDICINE', 'gid': 134709480},
{'name': 'Другая Музыка', 'gid': 35486626},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\trip-hop', 'gid': 27683540},
{'name': 'Depeche Mode', 'gid': 125927592}]


x = [{'gid': 35486626},{'gid': 134709480},{'gid': 27683540}]
```

Как видно, в обоих списках присутствуют одинаковые значения.
Так вот, каким образом можно сравнить эти два списка так, что бы вернуть список с данными из списка `х`,  но дополненными ключ-значение name из другого списка.
т.е. в итоге я должен получить список формата:

```
список= [{'name': 'Другая Музыка', 'gid': 35486626},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\trip-hop', 'gid': 27683540},
{'name': 'Бренд одежды | MEDICINE', 'gid': 134709480}]
```

Comment: Словари всегда с 2 элементами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дополню своим решением.
Предварительно замерим производительность предложенного выше красивого варианта от @Pavel:

```
%timeit [dict_group for gid in x for dict_group in dict_groups if dict_group["gid"] == gid["gid"]]
8.65 µs ± 1.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Мой вариант использует скорость встроенного оператора **in**. Правда предварительно надо извлечь значения ключей ***'gid'*** из списка.
Итак

```
 x_val = [d["gid"] for d in x]
 rez = [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
```

и проведем замеры:

```
%timeit x_val = [d["gid"] for d in x]
725 ns ± 58.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
    
%timeit [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
2.5 µs ± 212 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Итого - чуток быстрее и немного понятнее.  А читабельность - считается ).
Кроме того, можно рассмотреть вариант с перемещением списка значений  ключа ***'gid'*** из списка ***x*** не в конструкцию "список", а в конструкцию "кортеж".  Просто заменить квадратные скобки на круглые не пойдет. Так создается ***генератор***, а не кортеж!!
Я сам несколько раз так ошибался - ставишь скобки - думаешь кортеж... Ан-нет  -  будет генератор )
А генератор после прохода "исчерпывается", поэтому его надо вычислять на каждой итерации.  Итак, кортеж:

```
 x_val = tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)
 rez = [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
```

Оценим изменение в производительности:

```
%timeit x_val = tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)
1.55 µs ± 81.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
    
%timeit [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
2.19 µs ± 93.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Итоговый вариант получается в два раза быстрее красивого "лобового решения".
Можно ли записать итоговый вариант в виде "однострочника"?  Конечно можно:

```
%timeit [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)]
11.9 µs ± 756 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each))
```

Не знаю уж почему, но однострочник оказывается медленнее. Так что рекомендации учебников везде использовать "компрехенсив" - надо проверять. ;-)

Ну и вариант - чемпион.  Компрехенсив множество!

```
x_val = {d["gid"] for d in x}
rez = [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
```

с таймингом:

```
%timeit x_val = {d["gid"] for d in x}
731 ns ± 52.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
1.62 µs ± 120 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Однострочник наверное медленнее потому, что timeit выполняет его много раз, в том числе оно выполняет то, что в предыдущем варианте у вас получается вынесено из этого цикла и посчитано заранее. Да - там генератор и отдельно он вроде быстро выполняется и не должен так влиять, если сложить оба тайминга вроде будет всё-равно сильно быстрее. Но всё же, всё же. Проверять надо как-то по-другому, в реальной жизни однострочник не должен быть медленнее, если там те же конструкции.

Comment: Хотя вы правы - вынес в функции и всё-равно однострочник в 4 раза медленнее оказался. Странно

Comment: @CrazyElf да я сам в шоке.
Вот запостил вопрос к "грандам":
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144181/%d0%92%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-comprehencive-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%80%d1%83%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам всем за участие!

Answer (score 5):

```
In [5]: [dict_group for gid in x for dict_group in dict_groups if dict_group["gid"] == gid["gid"]]
Out[5]:
[{'name': 'Другая Музыка', 'gid': 35486626},
 {'name': 'Бренд одежды | MEDICINE', 'gid': 134709480},
 {'name': 'E:\\music\\trip-hop', 'gid': 27683540}]
```

Comment: Спасибо, за предложенный вариант!

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_groups = [{'name': 'Новые Альбомы', 'gid': 4100014},
{'name': 'Synthpop [Futurepop, Retrowave, Electropop]', 'gid': 8564},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\leftfield', 'gid': 101522128},
{'name': 'Бренд одежды | MEDICINE', 'gid': 134709480},
{'name': 'Другая Музыка', 'gid': 35486626},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\trip-hop', 'gid': 27683540},
{'name': 'Depeche Mode', 'gid': 125927592}]

x = [{'gid': 35486626},{'gid': 134709480},{'gid': 27683540}]

x_gids = [x_dict['gid'] for x_dict in x]
gid_names = {dict_group['gid'] : dict_group['name'] for dict_group in dict_groups}

result_dicts = [{'name': gid_names[x_gid], 'gid': x_gid} for x_gid in x_gids]

print(result_dicts)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = [{'gid': 35486626},{'gid': 134709480},{'gid': 27683540}]
new = [elem['gid'] for elem in x]

res = [elem for elem in dict_groups if elem['gid'] in new]
print(res)
```