# Вложенный comprehension необходимо оптимизировать вручную?

Tags: python, циклы, list, оптимизация, список

Вопрос к "**грандам**".
Отвечая на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144034/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-python-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80/1144151?noredirect=1#comment1980662_1144151), где есть такие данные:

```
dict_groups = [{'name': 'Новые Альбомы', 'gid': 4100014},
{'name': 'Synthpop [Futurepop, Retrowave, Electropop]', 'gid': 8564},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\leftfield', 'gid': 101522128},
{'name': 'Бренд одежды | MEDICINE', 'gid': 134709480},
{'name': 'Другая Музыка', 'gid': 35486626},
{'name': 'E:\\music\\trip-hop', 'gid': 27683540},
{'name': 'Depeche Mode', 'gid': 125927592}]


x = [{'gid': 35486626},{'gid': 134709480},{'gid': 27683540}]
```

Предложил такое решение:

```
x_val = tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)
rez = [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
```

Оценим производительность:

```
%timeit x_val = tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)
1.55 µs ± 81.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
1.99 µs ± 159 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Можно ли записать итоговый вариант в виде "однострочника"? Конечно можно:

```
%timeit [dict_el for dict_el in dict_groups if dict_el["gid"] in tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)]
11.9 µs ± 756 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Не знаю почему, но однострочник оказывается медленнее. Так что, рекомендации учебников везде использовать "компрехенсив" (*comprehension*) - надо проверять.

Складывается впечатление, что выражение `(d["gid"] for d in x)` вычисляется в компрехенсиве 7 раз, хотя не зависит от переменных внутри.
Ведь 7*1,55 + 1,99 = 12,84, что примерно совпадает с временем однострочника.

Comment: Кстати, если сделать список вместо генератора, то работать будет быстрее, но разница всё-равно останется в 2-3 раза между вариантами.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По-моему, вы все правильно поняли - кортеж `tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)` создается и проверяется на каждой итерации цикла в однострочной версии.

```
import dis
```

---

```
In [71]: s = '''[dict_el
    ...:         for dict_el in dict_groups
    ...:         if dict_el["gid"] in
    ...:             tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)]'''

In [72]: dis.dis(s)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x000002094FE22270, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0

  2           6 LOAD_NAME                0 (dict_groups)
              8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x000002094FE22270, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                34 (to 40)

  2           6 STORE_FAST               1 (dict_el)

  3           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (dict_el)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 ('gid')
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR

  4          14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (tuple)
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x000002094FE22030, file "<dis>", line 4>)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('<listcomp>.<genexpr>')
             20 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             24 GET_ITER
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             30 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             32 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4
             34 LOAD_FAST                1 (dict_el)
             36 LIST_APPEND              2
             38 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   40 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <genexpr> at 0x000002094FE22030, file "<dis>", line 4>:
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    2 FOR_ITER                14 (to 18)
              4 STORE_FAST               1 (d)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 ('gid')
             10 BINARY_SUBSCR
             12 YIELD_VALUE
             14 POP_TOP
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

PS как вы уже и сами заметили при использовании генератора - `x_val = (d["gid"] for d in x)` - `x_val` выдохнется после первой же проверки и это ускорит будущие проверки (результат всех последующих проверок будет неправильным). Но даже при использовании кортежа `x_val = tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)` - это работает заметно быстрее по сравнению с однострочной версией.

Замеры времени для списка, состоящего из 70.000 словарей:

```
In [55]: big = dict_groups * 10000

In [56]: len(big)
Out[56]: 70000
```

---

```
In [67]: %%timeit
    ...: x_val = tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)
    ...: rez = [dict_el for dict_el in big if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
    ...:
    ...:
6 ms ± 566 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [68]: %%timeit
    ...: rez = [dict_el for dict_el in big if dict_el["gid"] in tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)]
    ...:
    ...:
61.5 ms ± 913 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [69]: %%timeit
    ...: rez = [dict_el for dict_el in big if dict_el["gid"] in set(d["gid"] for d in x)]
    ...:
    ...:
55.9 ms ± 4.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Самый быстрый вариант** - разница в скорости будет более заметна если в `x` будет намного больше элементов. Причина тому - скорость проверки `in list(...)` - `O(n)`, когда для множества: `in set(...)` всего `O(1)`:

```
In [70]: %%timeit
    ...: x_val = set(d["gid"] for d in x)
    ...: rez = [dict_el for dict_el in big if dict_el["gid"] in x_val]
    ...:
    ...:
5.1 ms ± 72.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Вывод:** - если важна скорость - надо пробовать и сравнивать результаты, а не слепо доверять шаблонам и рекомендациям. Не всегда однострочник лучше)

Comment: ну это как то "пошло".  То есть ноль оптимизации?
Это извиняюсь уже в фортране 77 делали...
А в чем причина невозможности оптимизировать?

Comment: и второе  -  вложенные компрехенсивы - не использовать.
Такое резюме получается?

Comment: кстати, я переделал пример на кортежи.  так как исходный вариант с генератором был ошибочным. Генератор обнулялся ))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, вы задаете вопросы, на которые у меня нет ответов) Возможно интерпретатор что-то и пытаеется оптимизировать, но судя по времени - у него это не слишком хорошо получается

Comment: Спасибки! А тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510875/is-nested-comprehensive-non-optimized-in-python    меня тупо начали минусить .... хоть не спрашивай...

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, не драматизируйте: один минус - это еще не "начали минусовать", а всего лишь "кто-то минусанул".

Comment: @insolor ну да, есть такая украинская черта - "бідкаться".
Согласен. Начали плюсовать ))

Comment: Для полноты картины надо было бы ещё в разных интерпретаторах/компиляторах попробовать позапускать. PyPy там всякий и т.д. Возможно, кто-то из них и оптимизирует такое. А может и нет.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Разница между list comprehension и explicit loop (явный цикл).

- `list comprehension` изначально всего лишь более лаконичный способ создания объекта типа `list`, а не средство оптимизации - [PEP 202 -- List Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).
- `list comprehension` работает быстрее за счёт специальной инструкции для виртуальной машины - `LIST_APPEND`, а не за счёт отдельной, свойственной только ему способности к оптимизации. `LIST_APPEND` избавляет от поиска атрибута/метода `append` у объекта и последующего вызова этого метода, как это происходит в обычном цикле (`lst.append(new_item)`).
- Уж если бы такая оптимизация была в Python, то она бы работала и в обычном цикле.

Сравним два способа создания списка:

```
s1 = '''lst = []
for item in range(10):
    lst.append(item)'''
dis.dis(s1)
```

и

```
s2 = "lst = [item for item in range(10)]"
dis.dis(s2)
```

Инструкции исполняемые виртуальной машиной для наполнения списка соответственно:

```
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                14 (to 30)
             16 STORE_NAME               2 (item)

  3          18 LOAD_NAME                0 (lst)
             20 LOAD_ATTR                3 (append)
             22 LOAD_NAME                2 (item)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 POP_TOP
             28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14
```

и

```
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 14)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (item)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (item)
             10 LIST_APPEND              2
             12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
```

Отсюда и прибавка в производительности.

Вариант с обычным циклом можно ускорить следующим образом:

```
lst = []
append = lst.append
for item in range(10):
    append(item)
```

Уменьшаем цикл на одну инструкцию, убрав из него поиск атрибута. Встречал этот способ в участках кода, требующих быстрой работы, например во встроенных модулях. Почему интерпретатор не делает это сам? Думаю, по той же причине, что и оптимизацию в вопросе.

#### 2. Рассуждения на тему: "Почему Python не оптимизирует циклы?"

Как вам написали в английском [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62510875/2913477) - из-за возможных [side effects](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Нет гарантии, что во время перебора значений `my_lst` в этом примере, не происходит что-либо ещё.

```
for item in my_lst:
    print(item)
```

Дело в том, что самостоятельно цикл `for` в `my_lst` не копается, в отличии от языка **С**, например. [Каждая последовательность](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) в Python знает как себя перебирать. Она это делает посредством своего итератора. Цикл `for` только запрашивает у неё очередное значение, а уж как его найти, отдать и какие операции выполнить по ходу дела, она решает сама.  Также `my_lst` может быть как встроенным типом, так и созданным пользователем.

Соответственно, работу цикла `for` можно представить так:

```
my_iterator = iter(my_lst)        # запрос итератора у последовательности
while True:
    try:
        item = next(my_iterator)  # перебор значений
        print(item)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

**Вывод:**

Интерпретатор не может зафиксировать значения `tuple(d["gid"] for d in x)`, сохранив этот кортеж (как сделал автор вопроса вручную) и использовать его во всех последующих итерациях, так как он не знает логику итератора `x`. Может этот итератор формирует значения в зависимости от текущего времени и значения будут каждый раз разные?

**Пример кастомизированного типа list**

В данном случае, итератор пишет слово "hello" при каждом запросе значения, а может делать что угодно, например, считать запросы, писать в лог и т.д.

```
class My_list(list):
    def __iter__(self):
        self.list_iter = super().__iter__()
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        print("hello")
        return self.list_iter.__next__()

my_lst = My_list()
my_lst.append(1)
my_lst.append(2)
my_lst.append(3)
my_lst.append(4)
my_lst.append(5)

for item in my_lst:
    print(item)
```

**Output**

```
hello
1
hello
2
hello
3
hello
4
hello
5
```

---

Также Python имеет методы:

- `__setitem__`
- `__getitem__`
- `__getattribute__`
- `__getattr__`
- и т.д.

которые позволяют кастомизировать поведение объектов в соответствии с нуждами пользователя.

Поэтому он не может принимать оптимизационные решения типа `append = lst.append`

```
lst = []
append = lst.append
for item in range(10):
    append(item)
```

так как получение атрибута может обрабатываться в методе `__getattribute__` объекта `lst`. И сделав такую оптимизацию, он изменит логику работы программы.

Comment: Благодарю!
Блестяще!

Comment: добавил в сохраненные ради ваших ответов!